# The unity of a subdomain

Tags: abstract-algebra, alternative-proof

Let $D$ be an integral domain and $R$ a subdomain , I'm trying to show that both $R$ and $D$ have the same unity. I did it using the fact that $1$ and $0$ are the only idempotent elements inside any integral domain. I'm trying to do it in another way which is the following:

Since $R$ is a subdomain it has unity call it $c$, let $a\in R$ then $ac=a$ since we can cancel we get that $c$ which is in $R$ is equal to $1$ then $1\in R$.

I'm not really confident this right. If this is wrong what other way is there that does not use the fact that there are two idempotent elements in an integral domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your definition of subdomain requires that the unity is non zero, then you have for this unity $c\in R$

$$
cc=ce
$$

where $e$ is the unity of $D$, because both, by definition, give $c$. Hence

$$
c(c-e)=0
$$

and, since $c\ne0$, $c=e$.

Of course, this is just using that $c$ is idempotent. Which it is, so why bother?

Comment: Why are we sure there exists any unit in $R$?

Comment: @user10444 Please, spell out your definitions, because they surely are non standard.

Comment: A unit is an element which has a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: @user10444 I've changed "unit" into "unity" (just a mistyping).

Comment: I get it know, thank you for your answer. My proposed method is wrong, right?

Comment: @user10444 It's not wrong; you're only not using the right element. You need to assume $a\ne0$; then why not using the same $c$?

Comment: Thank you for indicating the mistake :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $ \ c \ $ be the unity of the subdomain $ \ R \ $ and $ \ e \ $ the unity of the domain $ \ D \ $ itself. For any $ \ a \in R \ $, $ \ ea = ca \ $ and thus $ \ (e-c)a=0 \ $.

Hope this is right.

Comment: I believe that you should add $a \not= 0$

Comment: My mistake, thought it doesn't matter much though since you get the idea :)

Comment: @user10444: There is no need to add the condition $a\ne0$. The condition that Steve gave implies that $ea=ca$ for any non-zero $a\in R$, so $(e-c)a=ea-ca=0$ for any non-zero $a\in R$. Now, in *your* approach, the condition $a\ne0$ is necessary to draw your conclusion.